# subroutine taking an array as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, scope

In the following program, the user is supposed to enter a `String` (name of a City) and the program should return the index of the corresponding City in the array.

But I get an error, in the subroutine `indexCities` the following message:

> "nameCity cannot be resolved".

I guess it is a problem of variable scoping but I don't figure out how I should do.
Thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class villes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cities[] = {"Vierzon","Salbris","Nouans","LB","LFSA","Orleans"};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nameCity = input.nextLine();
        indexCities(cities);
    }

    public static int indexCities(String cities[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            if(nameCity.equals(cities[i])) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `nameCity` is a _local_ variable in method `main()` and thus is not visible in method `indexCities()` - I suggest you read up on variable scopes. to fix it either pass `nameCity` as a second parameter or put the scanner inside `indexCities()`, whichever fits your needs.

Comment: it seems like you've forgotten a `return` statement in `indexCities()`. The compiler might get bitchy because of this...

Answer (score 3):

nameCity  is a local variable inside your main method. You can not access it outside the method. 
One option for you is to pass the nameCity also as an argument in indexCities method. Also return type of your indexCities method should be void since you are not returning anything.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    String cities[] = {"Vierzon","Salbris","Nouans","LB","LFSA","Orleans"};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String nameCity = input.nextLine();

    indexCities(cities, nameCity);

}

public static void indexCities(String cities[], String nameCity){

    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        if(nameCity.equals(cities[i])) {
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I thought every variable declared in main was accessible for other methods. I will not it know !

Comment: No problems, we all are learners here, we learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cities[] = { "Vierzon", "Salbris", "Nouans", "LB", "LFSA", "Orleans" };
    int index = indexCities(cities, "Vierzon");
    System.out.println("Index of city Vierzon is: " + index);
}

public static int indexCities(String cities[], String cityName) {
    List<String> cityList = Arrays.asList(cities);
    return cityList.indexOf(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope of variable `nameCity` is limited to main function. You can not access it outside of main function.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is out of scope when you try to use it inside the method `indexCities`. One solution is making the variable `nameCity` an instance variable by moving it's definition out of the main method, but your code can be improved in several ways too. Check some option below:

This will print the index of the city you're looking for inside the array:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class villes {

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String cities[] = {"Vierzon","Salbris","Nouans","LB","LFSA","Orleans"};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nameCity = input.nextLine();
    indexCities(nameCity, cities);  
  }

  public static void indexCities(String copyOfNameCity, String cities[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
      if(copyOfNameCity.equals(cities[i])) {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You you can improve it by making the method return a value. Like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class villes {

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String cities[] = {"Vierzon","Salbris","Nouans","LB","LFSA","Orleans"};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nameCity = input.nextLine();
    int cityIndex = indexCities(nameCity, cities);
      System.out.println(cityIndex == -1 ? "City not found" : "City found in index " + cityIndex);    
  }

  public static int indexCities(String nameCity, String cities[]){  
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
      if(nameCity.equals(cities[i])) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Another way is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cities[] = {"Vierzon", "Salbris", "Nouans", "LB", "LFSA", "Orleans"};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of city to be searched -> ");
        String nameCity = input.nextLine();
        int cityIndex = indexCities(nameCity, cities);
        System.out.println(cityIndex == -1 ? "City not found" : "Found at position " + cityIndex);
        input.close();
    }

    public static int indexCities(String cityName, String cities[]) {
        List<String> cityList = Arrays.asList(cities);
        return cityList.indexOf(cityName);
    }
}
```